# Odoo hide calculated field depend on condition on tree view

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

I have Odoo stock addon's *view_stock_history_report_tree* view:

```
<tree string="Stock Value At Date" create="0" delete="0">
                <field name="location_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="product_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="move_id"/>
                <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company"/>
                <field name="date"/>
                <field name="source"/>
                <field name="quantity" sum="# of Products "/>
                <field name="inventory_value" sum="Total Value"/>
            </tree>
```

I want to **hide computed quantity field if the sum not equal to 0**. I tried to add an attrs to quantity field by writing:

```
<field name="quantity" sum="# of Products " attrs="{'invisible': [('quantity', '=', 0)]}"/>
```

But nothing happens. It seems like attrs is not working on this field. I don't understand how can I reach computed quantity field by using attrs.

**Example:**

[image: Example:]

I would like to hide *Persona V* grouped field and *Horizon Zero Dawn* grouped field.

Comment: If you want to hide 'quantity' field when quantity is not zero then you need to do like this  attrs="{'invisible': [('quantity', !'=', 0)]}

Comment: I can't do that because syntax is incorrect.

Comment: in search bar add custom field where `QTY != 0`, you do not need more coding bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're telling Odoo:

*Make the value of the column quantity `invisible` if its value equals to 0.*

So you're hiding all the zeros of that column.

But first of all, take a look at this, just in case:

> You can't make invisible a column of a tree view, the behaviour of
>   `attrs` is different from the one of the form view. I mean, when you
>   add `attrs` to make a field invisible depending on a condition, the
>   behaviours in both views are different:
>
> **Form view**
>
> If the condition is fulfilled and the field must be invisible, it just
>   disappears, the label and the value are invisible.
>
> **Tree view**
>
> If the condition is fulfilled and the field must be invisible, only
>   the value is invisible, but not the label (in this case, the column).

So you'll always see the `quantity` column, just some rows will have an empty value.

**EDIT**

So I guess you want to hide *Persona V* and *Horizon Zero Dawn* groups because the sum of the quantity of their records is zero, don't you?

Then inherit from the model of the tree view and modify its `read_group` method. This will work for you:

```
@api.model
def read_group(self, domain, fields, groupby, offset=0, limit=None,
               orderby=False, lazy=True):
    # If user has grouped the tree view by location_id and product_id...
    if u'location_id' in groupby and u'product_id' in groupby:
        ids_to_show = []
        # Put here your code to fill in ids_to_show with the IDs of the records you want to show
        ...
        # Then, make the domain more restrictive:
        domain[0].append([u'id', u'in', [ids_to_show]])
        # The domain will automatically remove the groups with no
        # representation. For example, if the result of ids_to_show is [2, 7, 35],
        # and those three records have as product Last of Us (x2) and Call of
        # Duty, the agrupations of Persona V and Horizon Zero Dawn will be
        # invisible as they don't have records inside.
    return super(YourModel, self).read_group(
        domain, fields, groupby, offset=offset, limit=limit,
        orderby=orderby, lazy=lazy)
```

Comment: Maybe is there another method to achieve the same result?

Comment: What you want is to hide the whole tree column of `quantity` only if the sum of all the displayed records is different from 0, don't you?

Comment: I updated my question and added picture what exactly I want to hide.